# How to iterate through an array containing objects in Meteor implementing SimpleSchema

Tags: javascript, arrays, meteor, meteor-autoform, simple-schema

I have a simple schema implementation as follows. There is an array containing objects. Each object has a radio button. I need to extract the value of each radio button. How do I traverse through the array?

```
test_schema = new SimpleSchema ({


    object:{
        type:Array,

    },
    "object.$":{
        type:Object
    },

    "object.$.condition" :{
        type:String,
        autoform:{
            type: "select-radio-inline",
            options:[{label:'1', value:"one"}]
        },
    },


 "zod": {
    type: String,
     optional:true,
     custom: function () {

         alert(this.field('object').value);


     }
}
```

I tried an incremental approapch where I removed the array definition and just to retrieve the data from objets alone. Someethiing like this worked:

```
this.field('object.condition').value
```

However, after encompassing the object within an array, something like this does not work.

```
this.field('object.$.condition').value
```

What works is :

```
this.field('object.0.condition').value
```

This retrieves the first object's condition value. How do I, lets say extract other elements?

Comment: In js code where you have the object as a variable or in your simple-schema definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The '$' sign is a placeholder for the array index in the Schema definition.

When accessing actual instances you replace it with an actual array index.

So the first one has index 0, the next one has index = 1, and so on:

```
for (var i=0, i<object.length, i++) {
  console.log( i, this.field('object.'+i+'.condition').value
}
```

Comment: I got that, but how do I iterate through that?  I triend putting it  into a for loop but it didn't do much. Eg - for (var i =0, i<object.length, i++) { ... this.field('object.i.condition').value ...

Comment: The argument to the field function is a string, to create one that works you need to use the variable i, as in my answer. Not the letter i as in your comment.